# Map array to array of JSX components, but only update the right index in the array when there are prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
const FooComponent = (props) => {
  const inputsArray = props.arrayOfInputs.map(
    (field) => <Input value={props.inputValues[field.id].value} key={...}/>
  )
  return inputsArray
}
```

It renders a list of multiple  `<Input>`s, my `<Input>` is memoized so whenever there is a new value in `props.state.someInput.value` only the `<Input>` with the new value gets re-rendered. However, the `map()` function is always ran to its completeness, is there a way for javascript/react to not re-run the `map()` function and simply modify the element of the `inputsArray` that has new props?

I do not mean avoiding a re-render, my question is about avoiding the `map()` function from running. When the re-render of `FooComponent` is avoided then the `map()` does not run, but if an element inside `inputsArray` is re-rendered, the `map()` for the whole list still runs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, use `memo` which is stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

First, extract your input to a component and wrap with memo.

```
const InputComponent = React.memo((props) => {
  return <Input value={props.inputValues[field.id].value} key={...}/>
});
```

Next:

```
const FooComponent = (props) => {
  const inputsArray = props.arrayOfInputs.map(
    (field) => <InputComponent value={props.inputValues[field.id].value} key={...}/>
  )
  return inputsArray
}
```

The memoized input component will not re-render unless `props.inputValues[field.id].value` has changed

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I did not ask about avoiding a re-render, I was asking about avoiding the `map()` function from running. When the re-render of FooComponent is avoided then the `map()` does not run, but if an element inside `inputsArray` is re-rendered, the `map()` for the whole list still runs.

Comment: hmm, sry but If I understand correctly, that's not possible, since your `FooComponent` basically share the prop `inputValues` with your child `InputComponent`, there won't be a situation where one of your `input` has prop change but the `FooComponent` has no prop change.

Comment: If you avoid the re-rendering of a parent (FooComponent) directly, you are basically avoiding the re-rendering of all it's children. That's why `memo` is used on child components so they don't hinder the re-rendering of the parent by props change which they are not responsible of.